# Solving an underdetermined nonlinear system of equations in python

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a underdetermined system of nonlinear equations in python. At the moment my plan is to proceed as follows but unfortunately it does not work out. I'll give a small example.

I have this input data.

```
Lins = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 5, 2], [5, 2, 6]], 
                 [[7, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [5, 8, 7], [2, 1, 4]]], np.int32)
```

Each of the lines representing polynoms. Meaning `[1, 2, 3]` represents *1*x^2+2*x+3*, and `[5, 8, 7]` *5*x^2+8*x+7* and so on.

To "create" the equations for my system I do the following:

```
def f(x):
    X = np.array([x**2, x, np.ones_like(x)]).T
    return np.sum(Lins * X[:,None], axis=(1, 2))
```

So my plan is to get this two equations with the four unknowns x1-x4:

*1*x1^2+2*x1+3 + 4*x2^2+5*x2+6 + 1*x3^2+5*x3+6 + 5*x4^2+2*x4+6*

*7*x1^2+2*x1+3 + 4*x2^2+5*x2+6 + 5*x3^2+8*x3+7 + 2*x4^2+1*x4+4*

After that I import my solver, and define the solution vector b.

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
b = np.array([52, 62])
```

Finally, I try to solve the system:

```
x = least_squares(lambda x: f(x) - b, np.asarray((1,1,1,1,1)), bounds=(0, 1)).x
```

I am expecting four values representing the solutions for the 4 unknowns x1-x4. Unfortunately I get this error:

*ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,4,3) (4,1,3)*

For me it seems as if there is a mistake in the way I put my data into the `least_squares` solver. But I can`t figure out the problem. Or is `least_squares` not appropriate to solve underdetermined systems?

Thank you in advance for all of your help :)

Comment: The error is caused by `Lins * X[:,None]`, since these 2 matrices are of different shapes, they cannot be multiplied element wise.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. Could you also suggest how to do it correct? I thougth this should work because I have 3 values in each array of arrays and the 3 x-values x^2, x and 1?

Answer (score 0):

The [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is a very useful matrix for this problem.
If we create a 'vander' matrix using the function f argument x (=[x1, x2, x3, x4]), then we can create the equations you described in your plan.

```py
def f(x): ## x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
    X = np.vander(x, 3)  ## Vandermonde Matrix [[x^2 x 1] ...]
    return np.sum(Lins * X, axis=(1, 2))
```

I am less familiar with solving these systems and so I cannot say whether the rest of the program will produce the correct solutions.

Comment: Also, I believe in `x = least_squares(lambda x: f(x) - b, np.asarray((1,1,1,1,1)), bounds=(0, 1)).x`, `np.asarray((1, 1, 1, 1, 1))` should only have 4 1s `np.as.array((1, 1, 1, 1))`. However, if I am mistaken I may need to amend my solution